# C# Defined type of class variable

Tags: c#, oop

I'm not even sure if the title of this question is correct, but I wasn't sure how to describe the problem. Basically I have two following classes:

```
class A
{
    public B b { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string name { get; set;}
}
```

After I create an object of my `A` class, I'm trying to define class `B` variable name like so:

```
A classA = new A();
A.B.name = "TEST";
```

However, I keep getting the follow error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Obviously, I'm doing something completely wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised that A.B.name compiles. I'd say it should be A.b.name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call it like this:

```
A classA = new A();
classA.b = new B();
classA.b.name = "TEST";
```

The issue is that you need to instantiate the `b` property on `classA` instance you created.

Answer (score 10):

You haven't created instance of `B` so it is `null` (that is inside your instance of `A`). You can e.g. instantiate it inside constructor:

```
class A
{
    public B b { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        b = new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a constructor is probably the best answer, though the others are technically correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, class A and B are both through web services. I cannot change them. so, I cannot use this solution.

Comment: I guess I should've mentioned that in the question...sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is null. You need to instantiate `B` before you can reference it.

```
A classA = new A();
classA.B = new B();
classA.B.name = "TEST";
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize class B

```
A classA = new A();
classA.b = new B();
classA.b.name = "TEST";
```

Comment: This is syntactically wrong.  The first variable is named classA, so saying A.B = new B() is wrong; it should be classA.B = new B();  And that's even wrong, since the property on is a lower case b, so it should be classA.b = new B();

Comment: @Jim I'd say the question was wrong in the first place, confusing B and b.

Comment: The question was written in a way that might be easy to confuse the class names and variable names, but it isn't wrong; it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @Jim so public B b { get; set; } and later A.B.name = "TEST"; compile? Maybe I'm missing something, but I'd say that class A has a property called "b", not "B"; so the line "A.B.name..." does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of your class B.

```
A classAInstance = new A();
classAInstance.b = new B();
classAInstance.b.name = "TEST";
```